# Youtube Video Analytics: Views counter

Tags: video, youtube, view, analytics

Recently I've uploaded a [video in Youtube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hF2SLh9IbJo) and embedded it to this page http://hassadpress.com/sos.php  and share it in my facebook page.

Well I've been watching the stats in Facebook, Google Analytics (for the website hassadpress.com) and in Youtube, as I can conclud there should be over **300** views already for this video but Youtube currently showing only **106**

> I've been searching a lot around and I've found no reason why my video isn't showing the correct views number.

Can anybody help me out? perhaps I'm looking in the wrong way

#### One more thing, my video is embedded using Youtube Code and without the setting auto-play option

Comment: How does youtube calculate a view? Is it a view completion?

Comment: I believe it is just watching a couple of seconds max about 5 seconds

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not seeing any Google Analytics specific tracking for the video. I see analytics.js loading, but not anything specific to youtube video. There is a blog post called [How To Track YouTube Player Events in Google Analytics](http://www.bluefountainmedia.com/blog/track-youtube-player-events-google-analytics/), so I would try implementing that is you want more precise metrics about how users are interacting with the video.

Comment: Yeah, thanks but this is not what I want to have, I just want to know what Youtube is not showing the correct views counts, or if it is shown somewhere else